# how can I send an image binary via post to an API? nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multipart

I am getting the image binary like this:

```
axios.get("image-url.jpg")
```

I need to use the response for making a new POST request to another server

```
  const form = new FormData();
  const url = "post-url-here.com";
  form.append(
    "file",
    new ReadableStream(Buffer.from(file)),
    "image-test.jpg"
  );
  const config = {
    headers: {
      ...form.getHeaders(),
      Authorization:
        "Bearer token-here",
    },
  };
  axios.post(url, form, config);
```

Unfortunately that isn't working. The response I am getting is:

```
data: {
  message: 'This file is not compatible with the picture engine, please try another one',
  error: 'bad_request',
  status: 400,
  cause: []
}
```

How can I properly do that ?

edit:
form.getheaders is adding this headeer to the request:

```
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------783115116498484087556627'
```

all request headers:

```
headers: {
  Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------918731250556909112992344',
  Authorization: 'Bearer token-here',
  'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
},
```

all request information:

```
_header: 'POST /pictures/items/upload HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
  'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------116660171215340291632150\r\n' +
  'Authorization: Bearer token-here\r\n' +
  'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
  'Host: api.mercadolibre.com\r\n' +
  'Connection: close\r\n' +
  'Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n' +
  '\r\n',
```

Comment: do you save the image  "image-url.jpg"   on hard disk and then  select it  to  Post it to server  or need  to do it on the fly ?   for example:  get image from url -> post to server   without save the image?

Comment: Debug  form.getHeaders() ,  or log the entire Post request  using  a listen socket  in the way we can view the entire Post resquest header

Comment: Yes, I do need to do it on the fly. I am editing the question for adding the .getHeaders information

Comment: content-type is only a part of the entire Header .    Can you post the entire header please?

Comment: yes, that is the only header that the .getHeaders generate. I am editing again with all final headers for the request

Comment: we can try to download the image , save it , then  append it to the form and post to the server.   If we obtain more data in the header  we have the possibility to do it on the fly after.  See edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of POST Header:

```
POST /video-upload/ HTTP/1.1
Host: your host 
User-Agent: axios/0.21.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------219493771727403213993181042749
Content-Length: 99211703
Connection: keep-alive
```

as you can see there are important parts like:

```
POST /the-url/ HTTP/1.1
Host: your host 
Content-Length: the length in bytes of your image 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------219493771727403213993181042749
Connection: keep-alive
```

So your script do not read the images , your header is broken as status:400 response from Server says.

Try this (pseudo code) :

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

var im_config = {
    responseType: 'stream'
};

let im_url =  'image-url' ;

async function getImage() {
    let resp = await axios.get(im_url, im_config);
    //save the image
    resp.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test-image.jpg'));
}

getImage().then(function(result){

  console.log(result); 

  const form = new FormData();
  const url = "server url where send the form ";

  // interesting part 
  form.append('image', 'test-image.jpg');   
  axios.post(url, form, your-config);

});
```

It worked!  Ok.

To do it on the fly , try to abtain a refer to the downloaded image  from 'result' or 'resp' without saving the image.

Otherwise unlink downloaded image after POST is done.

```
fs.unlink('test-image.jpg', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: I added more information from my axios request. But I still could't find anything for Content-Length. May that be the problem ?

Comment: we can try to download the image , save it , then append it to the form and post to the server. If we obtain more data in the header we have the possibility to do it on the fly after. See edited answer.

Comment: yes it worked. The only problem is that I have to save and delete them otherwise I will have storage issues. Can you see any other way to do it on the fly without saving any file ?

Comment: I think you need to destroy the buffer too , unless nodejs do it for you when script end. 
But after the POST OK response seems to be simple  unlink/remove/delete the downloaded images.  So  one mission is accomplisced and the script works.

Comment: Please add  'Nodejs' to your Question Title

Comment: Allright, I'll implement a logic to unlink those images after post is done. thanks for your help